# Как установить статус участнику тг чата?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

из telegram api, нашел тему с [ChatMemberRestricted](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chatmemberrestricted)
Так вот, как выдавать ограниченный статус пользователям чата?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кажется то, что вам нужно уже описано [здесь](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/api/methods/restrict_chat_member.html)

А [тут](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/api/types/chat_permissions.html#aiogram.types.chat_permissions.ChatPermissions) подробнее про ChatPermissions

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types

from aiogram.types.chat_permissions import ChatPermissions
from aiogram.dispatcher.webhook import RestrictChatMember

bot = Bot(token="<ТОКЕН>") # вставьте токен

dp = Dispatcher()

@dp.message(commands=["test"])
async def cmd_start(message: types.Message):
    chat_id = 1 # ID чата
    user_id = 1 # ID пользователя, у которого меняем статус
    perms = ChatPermissions(can_send_messages=false)
    await bot(RestrictChatMember(chat_id=chat_id, user_id=user_id, permissions=perms));
    await message.answer("Ready!")

async def main():
    await dp.start_polling(bot)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: `from aiogram.methods.restrict_chat_member import RestrictChatMember
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aiogram.methods'`
Знаешь с чем связано(пробовал оба импорта из документации)

Comment: Да, моя ошибка. ```from aiogram.dispatcher.webhook import RestrictChatMember```